# OpenStreetMap on PhoneGap

Tags: events, cordova, click, openstreetmap

I want to use OpenStreetMap on a PhoneGap Application.

My Problem is that the click events are not fired on PhoneGap.

The code below works in a normal browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #basicMap {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
   <script>
  function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
    var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(7.55785346031189,50.3625329673905).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
    var zoom           = 18; 

    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(position, zoom );

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position);

    marker.events.register("click", map , function(e){ alert("click");
    });

    markers.addMarker(marker);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="basicMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When this code in PhoneGap to display the map, the map is shown and the marker is displayed. However when I click on the marker nothing happens.

Does anyone know why this does not work. I am using the Android Emulator and am using Eclipse to create the PhoneGapApplication.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander, this is no definitive answer, just a tip, but have you tried Leaflet.js to see if it works? Never developed for PhoneGap, but I have a couple of mobile sites using Leaflet on Android/iOS devices with no troubles.